# Unset ROS_HOSTNAME

Tags: ros, turtlebot, ros-hostname

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying now to set ROS_IP instead of ROS_HOSTNAME. How do I unset ROS_HOSTNAME?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40878/unset-ros_hostname/) by [buma676](https://answers.ros.org/users/2990/buma676/) on ROS Answers with karma: 91 on 2012-08-08

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [buma676](https://answers.ros.org/users/2990/buma676/) on 2012-08-08**:
wow I'm an idiot. Thanks! That was the answer I needed by the way so no one else needs to answer.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-08-08**:
In that case, click the checkbox at the answer to accept it, so people see that it's answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6877727/how-to-delete-the-exported-environment-variable

```
unset ROS_HOSTNAME
```

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2012-08-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would suggest that you remove any line like:

```
export ROS_HOSTNAME=...
```

from your .bashrc and create a new shell. Else you would have to call unset every time you create a new shell.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2012-08-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2